# Program in getting the path of url

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a program that user can enter video url  from the text box and then the url will will linked to html video source and html file will open to play the video

in program my 
if the path is 'C:\Film5 (copy)\Break_the_Barrier.mp4'

In the output file i am getting the below path
'C:ilm5 (copy)Break_the_Barrier.mp4'

I am not getting how to get the path

Thank you in advance

Comment: show your code snippet

Comment: Web browser security will not allow you to see the full path of the `<input type="file">` value.

Comment: Problem may be due to escape characters. try to put double slash or reverse slash